# How to solve an electrostatic second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this second order differential equation: 
$\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}(r\frac{dv}{dr}) =0 $, it’s solution is $v=c_1\ln(r)+c_2$ . Please someone help me to derive this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the equation one step at a time, integrating along the way.
$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}(r\frac{dv}{dr}) = 0$$
$$\frac{d}{dr}(r\frac{dv}{dr}) = 0$$
$$r\frac{dv}{dr} = c_1$$
$$v'(r) = \frac{c_1}{r}.$$
Can you complete the derivation from here?